# Drupal Lightbox2 fails W3C validation because of rel="lightbox[field_image][]" attribute

Tags: 7, media, javascript

I am using the latest Lightbox2 module for Drupal which works great but for my field images it adds a rel="lightbox[field_image][]" which fails W3C validation.

Is there a way to work around this so it passes validation? I have been reading somewhere to change the "rel" to "data-rel", but how would you apply this? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy the `lightbox2-insert-image.tpl.php` file into your own theme and change it there - but this will break the functionality of the module as javascript uses `rel` attribute multiple times.

You could refactor the javascript, change all occurrences where it accesses `rel` and change it to `data-rel` and create patch and submit it to drupal.org to the author of the issue as a request (or just submit issue now requesting this and wait if/until the maintainer does it).

On a personal note - why do you need it to pass W3C validation? Is it a project MUST requirement? If not, I would not waste any time on this as valid HTML is not that important any more, not even for SEO and indexing.

Edit: http://google.com is not passing W3C validation, I think that sends a message. (http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=google.com&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)